# Typescript root notation in module reference

Tags: typescript

Is there a slash notation in Typescript to indicate the root of the application. E.g. if I have a child module like this

```
root/common/mychildModule/myChildModule.ts
```

Is there a rootnotation to reference the root e.g.

```
import { myRootModule} from 'rootnotation/my-root-module';
```

Or is the only way to do this with ../../../my-root-module ?

Here is my tsconfig.js

```
{
     "compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"noEmit": true,
"noEmitHelpers": true,
"importHelpers": true,
"strictNullChecks": false,
"baseUrl": "./src/app",
"lib": [
"dom",
"es6"
],
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"types": [
  "hammerjs",
  "jasmine",
  "node",
  "source-map",
  "uglify-js",
  "webpack"
]
 },
   "exclude": [
"node_modules",
"dist"
],
"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
"forkChecker": true,
"useWebpackText": true
},
 "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
 "atom": {
"rewriteTsconfig": false
 }
 }
```

I also have a tsconfig for webpack

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src/app/",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.e2e.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./compiled",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `baseUrl` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "."
    }
}
```

And you can import modules anywhere as if you were in the `baseUrl`. In your case you can just do:

```
import { myRootModule } from 'my-root-module';
```

Documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: Thanks @Saravana . I added the baseurl as "baseUrl": "./src/app", since the my-root-module is located in there. Now I get the intellisense when I import the module in the child. However when i compile it tries to locate the my-root-module inside the myChildModule folder resulting in module not found. Do you know why it doesn´t look for the module under src/app

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` look like?

Comment: Hi @Saravana I also added the tsconfig.webpack.json

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your config files. Can you check if running `tsc` throws the error?

Comment: Then it probably has something to do with the other tools you are using that are not picking up this configuration.